# Get browser saying 'default browser'

Tags: php, browscap

I am using get_browser to keep statistics for my web site.  However, all of the results are browser = `'Default Browser'` and platform = `'unknown'`.  I checked phpinfo() and the browscap.ini path is correct.  What else would be causing this problem?  It does this in all browsers.

*My Code:*

```
print_r(get_browser(null, true));
```

Comment: See this page: http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php.html

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getallheaders()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$browser = $headers['User-Agent'];
```

Comment: Is that any different than $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']?

Comment: To tell the trouth I have never researched the topic but my best guess is: they should be just the same.

Comment: I tested that and it gives the same results.  Thanks, though.

Comment: How are you testing? I mean probably your test request is passing the default_browser flag if you are using curl or anything other than a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `get_browser()` since it uses the browscap file, which is constantly being updated and is more for seeing what the browser can do instead of getting the name of the browser. (browscap - short for **BROWS**er **CAP**abilities).  You can find many other ways to do this online, with a quick Google search.